# Use QGIS and Qt dialog forms

Tags: qgis, postgis, qt

I have a QGIS project where there are plots with a attributes like name of the owner, address of the owner, cultivate, and so on.

This plots are read from a PostGIS database. The future users of this project are not user of QGIS and is not an option to teach them things like "Go into properties->fields  calculators...etc".

They only need to use things like selections by name of the owner, or cultivate of the plot, town of the plot, ..., and show the plots with this attributes.

I can make a dialog form in Qt and create a postgres(postGIS) view from the selects fields, but I don't know how can QGIS refresh or read the created views.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you need. Do you really want to only load the features which correspond to the query? Or do you want to select the corresponding features in the layer of all features?

Comment: I would like to use created views for show or hide selected  plots since a form created in Qt for filter them (if possible).